# How to make direction rtl on React MUI <Menu /> component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using ReactJS with Material UI framework.

The app supports both rtl and ltr, and it works great.

However, it seems that for  and  component, the direction stays always ltr.
I guess it has something to do with where that 'new' component is inserted in the DOM hierarchy, but I didn't manage to solve it.

Below is a link to my demo, if you change the variable 'DIR' from ltr to rtl you will see that the inputs align to the right and Name1 input will be to the right of Name2 input (the desired behaviour).

The open menu will also be aligned to the right but that doesn't affect the menu items. I expect that instead of hello world {icon} I will see world hello {icon}.

[image: Edit menu rtl not working]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your property `maxWidth="xl"`has a wrong value. It should be `maxWidth="xs"`. Check the documentation for Grid https://material-ui.com/components/grid/. Also, check the dependencies. It looks like something is missing from this 3 steps: https://material-ui.com/guides/right-to-left/#opting-out-of-rtl-transformation

```
<Menu>
  <MenuItem>
     <ListItemIcon>
        <Icon />
     </ListItemIcon>
     <ListItemText primary="Sent mail" />
  </MenuItem>
  ...
</Menu>
```

Don't use Grid inside Menu, please

Comment: Thanks for the answer. maxWidth props is apllied to the <Conatiner /> component.
In this sandbox I really didn't follow all the steps, using ListItem and ListIcon really did solve the problem, thanks!

Comment: @RanST if this answer helped you to solve your problem. Please, vote as an answer. We are helping to get points. Thanks

Comment: It helped me a lot, sorry I forgot it.

Comment: I am glad it helped. Thanks